# В чём отличие между /, | и ) ? (регулярки)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

Вот несколько примеров:

```
preg_match('|slovo1(.*)slovo2|', $content, $output);
preg_match('/slovo1(.*)slovo2/', $content, $output);
preg_match('(slovo1(.*)slovo2)', $content, $output);
```

В чем отличие между всеми ними?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, эти символы служат только для отделения непосредственно шаблона от дополнительных служебных модификаторов. Теоретически, это могут быть любые символы и разницы в том какие - как бы нет. Чаще всего используются **/, #, ~, |**